# my app text is overlapping to going into a corner

Tags: java, android, android-studio, text, overlap

I recently started coding and I wanted to make an app that tells the percentage of a number but the UI keeps overlapping each other please help me solve this because this is my first app and I don't want the first app I made to fail

this is what it looks like in an android studio
[image]

and this is what it looks like in the emulator
[image]

```
package com.example.abhay.mathsucks;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView totalTextView;
    EditText percentageTxt;
    EditText numberTxt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        totalTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalTextView);
        percentageTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.percentageTxt);
        numberTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberTxt);


        Button calcBtn = (Button) findViewById(R. id.calcBtn);
        calcBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               float percentage = Float.parseFloat(percentageTxt.getText().toString());
               float dec = percentage / 100;
               float total = dec * Float.parseFloat(numberTxt.getText().toString());
               totalTextView.setText(Float.toString(total));
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

this the mainactivity.java file

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.abhay.mathsucks.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="443dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Large"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="%"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="353dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="206dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="What is"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="147dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="104dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/numberTxt"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter Number"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-4dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="370dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/percentageTxt"
        android:layout_width="337dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter Percentage"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="12dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="170dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="Of"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="170dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="272dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calcBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f92b2b"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="Calculate"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textColorLink="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="136dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="447dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.abhay.mathsucks.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#f92b2b"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/back"
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:ignore="IncludeLayoutParam" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

Comment: May you upload the xml file?

Comment: Please upload the xml file

Comment: And please add your screenshots directly to question. (Also, a tip: don't say that this is your first or second app: we can infer that from your question already).

Comment: ok xml will upload

Answer (score 0):

I think you messed up with Constraint-layout...
May this one help you

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:gravity="center"/>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="What is"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"

    android:gravity="center"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
       android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Percentage"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="%"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="of"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"

        android:gravity="center"/>


    <EditText
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Number"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Calculate"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```